# How do I restrict Subversion, using Apache WebDAV, to a specific URL?

Tags: apache, svn, ssl, webdav

I have a dedicated server, running Apache, with several virtual hosts, each with it's own domain. Subversion is setup to use WebDAV, via Apache and an SSL cert. The SSL cert is setup only for one of these domains.

I want to only be able to access the svn repos via the domain which has the SSL cert.

My problem, is that I can also access the repos via my other domains, and even though the SVN authentication is working regardless, I want to restrict to a single domain.

How would I go about configuring this scenario?

Comment: Show your httpd.conf!

Comment: I'd rather not put that out in the public view. Bad security practice.

Comment: Change hostnames, hide IPs (if any used). We (I) are not sensitives, I  can only say for your "I can also access the repos via my other domains" - "This isn't possible (except, maybe, one exotic way)"

Answer (score 0):

If you'll define SVN-Location inside virtualhost (name-based virtusl-hosts used), you'll see repositories **only** in this host

Dirty (partially ugly) sample

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName svn

    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /svn/repositories
        SVNListParentPath on

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion"
        AuthUserFile svn-auth-file
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

For repository REPO, only `http://svn/REPO` URL will show conent of repository, for any other virtualhost `/REPO` in URL must give "Path not found" (if real directory REPO doesn't exist, but - anyway - this is not access to repository)